# Equivalence between LHV and energy balance in combustion

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, physical-chemistry, combustion

I have seen in many textbooks the following equation for a combustion chamber
$$ \eta \, m_{fuel} LHV = m_{out}h_{out}(T_{out}) - m_{in}h_{in}(T_{in}). \quad (1) $$

Consider now the stoichiometric combustion of 1Kmol of CH4 with 2Kmol of O2 to produce 1Kmol of CO2 and 2Kmol of H2O. Assuming $\eta=1$ for simplicity, the equation above reads as
$$m_{fuel}LHV = H_{products}(T_{out}) - H_{reactants}(T_{in}). \quad (2)$$

However, the LHV is defined as the energy released after a unit mass of CH4 reacts with the stoichiometric quantity of O2 to produce the stoichiometric quantities of CO2 and H2O at constant pressure and temperature, i.e.,
$$m_{fuel}LHV = H_{reactants}(T_{in}) - H_{products}(T_{in}). \quad (3)$$

This released energy shoud reverse in heating what remains after the combustion of the CH4, i.e., the products --and the excess of O2, if there were-- from $T_{in}$ to $T_{out}$. Thus,
$$m_{fuel}LHV = H_{products}(T_{out}) - H_{products}(T_{in}). \quad (4)$$

Note that combining (3) and (4) we obtain $H_{products}(T_{out})=H_{reactants}(T_{in})$.

I do not find equations (2) and (4) to be equivalent. What is wrong?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

These two equations are the same or close. This can be seen from the definition of the LHV, which is the enthalpy difference between the reactants and the products. There might be a slight difference as the reference temperature is different from Tin.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58188/discussion-on-answer-by-user115350-equivalence-between-lhv-and-energy-balance-in).